# Xamarin.Forms HttpClient to RESTful webservice

Tags: ios, rest, httpclient, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms PCL application that access webservices via HttpClient. The app is working on Android but on iOS it doesn't connect to the webservices at all.  Do I need to create a proxy for iOS and REST?

I have read the information here http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/ but frankly, it just confused me. I tried to create the proxy, as set out but it didn't work. I will persevere if it is necessary though.

I also tried HttpWebRequest method but wasn't successful with that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to generate a proxy for WCF or SOAP. Rest should work just fine. This is how I implemented a GET to a REST service using HttpClient in a PCL.

```cs
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var result = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(result);
}
```

Of course the other verbs take a little bit more work.

Do you perhaps need a binding redirect in the app.config? Check out this blog post about adding a redirect: http://motzcod.es/post/78863496592/portable-class-libraries-httpclient-so-happy.

Here is an example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.5.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```